# #3115 error when retrieving data from SQLite database

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sqlite, air

I have this little piece of code to retrieve data from a local SQLite database (to an AIR app):

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.data.SQLConnection;
import flash.data.SQLStatement;
import flash.events.SQLEvent;

init();
var myConn;

function init():void
{
    var file = new File("app-storage:/game.sqlite");
    myConn = new SQLConnection();
    myConn.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, myTables);
    myConn.open(file);

}
function myTables(e)
{
    var sqlState = new SQLStatement();
    sqlState.sqlConnection = myConn;
    sqlState.text = "SELECT * FROM background";
    sqlState.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, showData);
    sqlState.execute();
}
//
function showData(e)
{
    trace("data: "+e);
}
```

It is only a "proof of concept" piece of code and it "lives" in the first frame of the timeline of the Flash IDE. What happens? **When I compile my SWF (AIR for iPhone), I get this error**:

```
SQLError: 'Error #3115: SQL Error.', details:'no such table: 'background'', operation:'execute', detailID:'2013'
```

I created a basic db with a Firefox extension (SQLiteManager). What can cause this error? **The table exists!**

Comment: Two different environments - Flash will have its own sqlite area, separate from Firefox's.

Comment: The sqlite db is packaged with the AIR app and it can regularly connect!

Comment: Yes, but you said you created the db in firefox. That's a completely different environment. Creating a db in one place for sqlite does not mean the same db will available in another package.

Comment: Ok, but it is available: ad I told you, I can connect it (init method).

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states the table does not exist.
So you didn't create it or well I don't know of an or.
[Anyway, here is a good proof of concept for you.](http://jurnal.tripmedia.ro/phone-book-adobe-air/1536.html)
Maybe that one you could try to make work on a phone.

[EDIT]
You might want to try something like this then.

```
file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("tut.db");
myConn = new SQLConnection();
try{
  myConn.open(file , SQLMode.CREATE);
}catch(e:SQLError){
  Alert.show("SQL Error Occured: ", e.message);
}
```

Comment: The table really exists: I found this same issue by searching online but none seems to post the solution (and the solution is not adding a table that does not exist!). Moreover, I loaded the same db in DBManager and other db tools and the table is there! The error is clear but it's misleading.

Comment: Finally, I found something working here: http://www.flashmove.com/forum/showthread.php?t=34778 The problem lied in the way I referenced the db file.

Comment: so details:'no such table: is actually true. Whatever DB it was connecting to the table did not exist.

Comment: Well, there was no db connected at all, but AS was trying to execute the query anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path to database is right, if you can see the table in you database, then the path is wrong, it could be looking to some other database. just an idea

Comment: Could it also be file permission issues?

Comment: By default var db:File = dir.resolvePath("Database.db"); creates/loads  the database from/to bin-debug directory under your project unless you explicitly define the path. if the the database is inside your project then there is no any issues with permission since flash builder assigns  appropriate  permission on creations but if it is outside the project directory it could be the issue.